# Compile tensorflow 1.15 gpu from source failed

Tags: tensorflow, compiler-errors

> ```
> 注意: 包含文件:  .\tensorflow/python/lib/core/safe_ptr.h  # can't compile tensorflow
> 注意: 包含文件:   .\tensorflow/c/c_api.h
> 注意: 包含文件:    .\tensorflow/c/tf_attrtype.h
> 注意: 包含文件:    .\tensorflow/c/tf_datatype.h
> 注意: 包含文件:    .\tensorflow/c/tf_status.h
> 注意: 包含文件:    .\tensorflow/c/tf_tensor.h
> 注意: 包含文件:     D:\DIYPrograms\VS2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\stdbool.h
> 注意: 包含文件:   .\tensorflow/c/eager/c_api.h
> tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(633): error C2664: “bool tensorflow::`anonymous-namespace'::Initialize::<lambda_f7579dace1c8cf1b2dde15b61bc2fe59>::operator
> ```
>
> ()(const char *,PyUFuncGenericFunction,const std::array<int,3> &)
> const”: 无法将参数 2 从“void (__cdecl *)(char **,npy_intp *,npy_intp *,void
> *)”转换为“PyUFuncGenericFunction”
> tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(634): note: 在匹配目标类型的范围内没有具有该名称的函数
> tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(637): error C2664: “bool tensorflow::`anonymous-namespace'::Initialize::<lambda_f7579dace1c8cf1b2dde15b61bc2fe59>::operator ()(const char *,PyUFuncGenericFunction,const std::array<int,3> &) const”: 无法将参数 2 从“void (__cdecl *)(char **,npy_intp *,npy_intp *,void *)”转换为“PyUFuncGenericFunction” tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(638): note: 在匹配目标类型的范围内没有具有该名称的函数 tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(641): error C2664: “bool tensorflow::`anonymous-namespace'::Initialize::<lambda_f7579dace1c8cf1b2dde15b61bc2fe59>::operator
> ()(const char *,PyUFuncGenericFunction,const std::array<int,3> &)
> const”: 无法将参数 2 从“void (__cdecl *)(char **,npy_intp *,npy_intp *,void
> *)”转换为“PyUFuncGenericFunction”
> tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(641): note: 在匹配目标类型的范围内没有具有该名称的函数
> tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(644): error C2664: “bool tensorflow::`anonymous-namespace'::Initialize::<lambda_f7579dace1c8cf1b2dde15b61bc2fe59>::operator ()(const char *,PyUFuncGenericFunction,const std::array<int,3> &) const”: 无法将参数 2 从“void (__cdecl *)(char **,npy_intp *,npy_intp *,void *)”转换为“PyUFuncGenericFunction” tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(645): note: 在匹配目标类型的范围内没有具有该名称的函数 tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(648): error C2664: “bool tensorflow::`anonymous-namespace'::Initialize::<lambda_f7579dace1c8cf1b2dde15b61bc2fe59>::operator
> ()(const char *,PyUFuncGenericFunction,const std::array<int,3> &)
> const”: 无法将参数 2 从“void (__cdecl *)(char **,npy_intp *,npy_intp *,void
> *)”转换为“PyUFuncGenericFunction”
> tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(649): note: 在匹配目标类型的范围内没有具有该名称的函数
> tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(652): error C2664: “bool tensorflow::`anonymous-namespace'::Initialize::<lambda_f7579dace1c8cf1b2dde15b61bc2fe59>::operator
> ()(const char *,PyUFuncGenericFunction,const std::array<int,3> &)
> const”: 无法将参数 2 从“void (__cdecl *)(char **,npy_intp *,npy_intp *,void
> *)”转换为“PyUFuncGenericFunction”
> tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc(653): note: 在匹配目标类型的范围内没有具有该名称的函数
> Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build

Comment: Hi @Smith Tom - I see you're new in the StackOverflow I highly recommend you add more context to your question. This give you a higher chance of someone helping you with the problem. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some advices

Answer (score 0):

I used virtualenv with python3 and met excatly the same error as you described when compiling tenorflow r1.14 & r1.15.
Then I tried virtualenv with python2, things just went smoothly and compilation succeed. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me your version of  python2 and tensorflow which has been complied successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a possible solution: [FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41086#issuecomment-656833081)

> There is a change in numpy 1.19 that breaks the build. Open tensorflow\python\lib\core\bfloat16.cc and make the following changes:

> Around line # 508, is the function CompareUFunc, add "const" to the parameters, like this:

```
template void CompareUFunc(char** args, npy_intp const* dimensions, npy_intp const* steps,
void* data) {
BinaryUFunc<bfloat16, npy_bool, Functor>(args, dimensions, steps, data);
}
```

> Line # 493, is the function BinaryUFunc add "const" here too:

```
template <typename InType, typename OutType, typename Functor>
void BinaryUFunc(char** args, npy_intp const* dimensions, npy_intp const* steps,
void* data) { }
```

> You should be able to get past this error.